# will Guava Map Cache shrink when keys are removed

Tags: garbage-collection, guava

```
private Cache<Object, String> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .concurrencyLevel(4)
        .expireAfterAccess(24, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .initialCapacity(1024)
        .maximumSize(1_00_000)
        .build();
private ConcurrentMap<Object, String> cacheMap = cache.asMap();
```

this is my code, it's simple and it's just creating a Guava map cache.
question is, if I remove() keys from this map, will GC be able to claim memory back from this map? without using weakReference(I am not storing nest objects like Set or Map etc...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes

From [Guava's `Cache.asMap` javadoc](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#asMap--) (emphasis mine):

> Returns a view of the entries stored in this cache as a thread-safe map. **Modifications made to the map directly affect the cache.**

And from [Guava's **Cache Explained** wiki page](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#explicit-removals):

> At any time, you may explicitly invalidate cache entries rather than waiting for entries to be evicted.

You might want to check the whole wiki page instead of the section I highlighted.

Comment: thanks, but invalidate() is for eviction feature, not the question I asked. I wanted to know under the cover, will impl of Guava cache shrink the size of the arrayRef to the objects, after it expanded before.

Comment: @linehrr [Yes, according to the source code](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/cache/LocalCache.java): `LocalManualCache` returns is internal `ConcurrentMap` through `asMap`. So the underlying map is indeed shrinked.